# get a list of all schemas referenced in an XML document

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

In C#, how can I get a list of all XSD schemas referenced in an XML file, including those referenced via `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a [XmlUrlResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlurlresolver.aspx) and then create a list of the XSD while loading the document.